# Troubleshooting extra space(s) in HTML

Tags: html, button, formatting

Some where in this code is a extra space(s). Can someone help me find it? It's driving me crazy. Thank you! I found only one and I feel like there is still just one more extra space that is messing up my formatting.

Can anyone spot the devil? Or maybe I'm missing something bigger?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Selz Plugin</title>
<link href="http://cdn.selz.com/jquery/1.0.3/jquery.selz.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 
<li{list-style-type: none;}><a href="http://selz.co/1triLby"></a></li>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.selz.com/jquery/1.0.3/jquery.selz.min.js"></script><script>
$(function () {
$.selz({
buttonBg: "#60aae0",
buttonText: "#fff",
prefetch: true,
onDataReady: function ($link, data) {
$link.html('<p align="center"><img src="https://static.squarespace.com/static/53752a6de4b0aefc671bc01d/t/53e42d7be4b0c4f03d1abbde/1407462784739/Buy$35?format=300w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="</p>' + data.Title + '">'); 
},
onModalOpen: function ($link) {
console.log("Overlay opened!");
},
onPurchase: function (data) {
console.log(data);
},
onProcessing: function (data) {
console.log(data);
}
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see the extra space in the browser? At the beginning of the body? It may be margin of the `li` element.

Comment: It's below the image...can't get it to go away! Thank for replying!

Answer (score 0):

The `'" alt="</p>' + data.Title + '">'` should be `'" alt="' + data.Title + '"></p>'`. You misplaced the `</p>`. If there is still some space below the image, set the image’s CSS `display` property to `inline`. Also you should set `li`’s `margin` to zero.

There are also other issues with your markup. You should [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) it and overall create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E.g. the `<li{list-style-type: none;}>` is not a valid markup and `li` element is not allowed to stand outside `ul` or `ol`.